# Question on Traversing an HTML table with JavaScript and DOM Interfaces

Tags: javascript

I followed the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces

But I have 2 things I can't figure out.

The first is how do I add a class name for all the td elements?

The second, is how do I inject this table into a div named "main",
rather than document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

I don't really understand the [0] at the end of the document.getElementsByTagName("body"), why is it necessary?

Comment: It's always better on this site to provide a useful, testable, example of your own code. Normally, when putting together a sample like that, you end up coming to your own conclusion.  @Nikki9696 has given you a good answer, but you should also try to ask one question at a time on your posts.

Answer (score 1):

> The first is how do I add a class name for all the td elements?The
> first is how do I add a class name for all the td elements?

classList.add

> The second, is how do I inject this table into a div named "main"

getElementById

> I don't really understand the [0] at the end of the
> document.getElementsByTagName("body")

Because getElementsByTagName is generic. It can return multiples for any tag. [0] says "give me the first", and since it's BODY, we pretty much are sure there's only one.

```js
    function start() {
        // get the reference for the body
        var mybody = document.getElementById("main");

        // creates <table> and <tbody> elements
        mytable = document.createElement("table");
        mytablebody = document.createElement("tbody");

        // creating all cells
        for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            // creates a <tr> element
            mycurrent_row = document.createElement("tr");

            for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                // creates a <td> element
                mycurrent_cell = document.createElement("td");
                mycurrent_cell.classList.add("myClass");
                // creates a Text Node
                currenttext = document.createTextNode("cell is row " + j + ", column " + i);
                // appends the Text Node we created into the cell <td>
                mycurrent_cell.appendChild(currenttext);
                // appends the cell <td> into the row <tr>
                mycurrent_row.appendChild(mycurrent_cell);
            }
            // appends the row <tr> into <tbody>
            mytablebody.appendChild(mycurrent_row);
        }

        // appends <tbody> into <table>
        mytable.appendChild(mytablebody);
        // appends <table> into <body>
        mybody.appendChild(mytable);
        // sets the border attribute of mytable to 2;
        mytable.setAttribute("border","2");
    }

start();
```

```css
.myClass {
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```